# How to keep the size of a label or frame the same within tkinter python

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, tkinter

I am new to programming and was hoping for some help.

I am using tkinter with python and was wanting to have a label / frame that would stay the same size, even if the text changes. Now when the text changes the size of the label changes depending on the text.

I have posted the code below and a screen shot comparison.

[image: Now they are different sizes but I could like them to be the same size]

```
result_frame = tkinter.Frame(main_window, width=200, height=5, background="green", relief="sunken", borderwidth=3)
result_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
result_text = tkinter.StringVar()
result_label = tkinter.Label(result_frame, textvariable=result_text, background="green",
                             height=2, font=font_style, justify="center")
result_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Comment: Have you tried simply giving the label a fixed width?

Comment: lmao nope ... thanks